# Gostaria de só usar o grid do bootstrap pra deixar responsivo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Como posso utilizar apenas grid do bootstrap só pra deixar responsivo, porque acabo nao conseguindo customizar meus inputs no css por causa do proprio bootstrap

Comment: **Felipe** edite sua pergunta e esclareça seu problema, você pode sim customizar os elementos `input` utilizando o Bootstrap.

Comment: Você pode copiar o código que quer do [CSS do Bootstrap](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc pode usar apenas o Grid do Bootstrap tranquilamente. Repare que quando vc faz o Download da versão completa do Bootstrap direto to site oficial dentro do `.zip` vem uma opção de arquivo `.css` que contem apenas o Grid, vc pode consultar aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/contents/#precompiled-bootstrap

De qualquer forma aqui está o link do CSS apenas do Grid direto do projeto oficial do Bootstrap no GitHub https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css

Veja a imagem abaixo para entender melhor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]