# Usar bootstrap com sass de forma semântica e seletiva

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, sass, scss

Quando se fala em Sass e Bootstrap a recomendação/vantagem que mais se encontra por ai é, *"importe apenas o que você vai usar, assim seu css final será menor e conterá apenas as partes do bootstrap que você está usando e não o bootstrap todo."*

Nossa isso é ótimo mas a "pergunta de um milhão" é como fazer isso?

Aqui no meu caso eu estou usando npm e tenho o boostrap e o sass instalado via npm (bootstrap no node_modules).

No exemplo abaixo eu tenho o html de uma `navbar`, no exemplo as classes bootstrap são aplicadas diretamente no html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria-controls="conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Alterna navegação">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="conteudoNavbarSuportado">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(página atual)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ação</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Outra ação</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Algo mais aqui</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Desativado</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-label="Pesquisar">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Tenho também um arquivo ***home.sass*** e ***home.ts*** que fazem a importação do bootstrap e gera o arquivo final concatenado via webpack.

home.sass:

```
@import '~bootstrap';
//Importação para gerar o css
```

home.ts

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
//importação do bootstrap.js para gerar o .js final
```

O exemplo funciona como esperado, mas nesse caso eu estou importando o bootstrap inteiro.
Uma outra critica que fazem é usar as classes do bootstrap diretamente no html, perdendo-se assim a semântica do nome das classes e acaba-se tendo um código html muito poluído, esse código é um exemplo simples de uma navbar tirado da documentação do bootstrap mas eu tenho código de aplicações bem mais poluídos que isso, cheios de `py-x, mr-auto, p-0, align-items-x` dentre outras classes.
Infelizmente ao pesquisar eu só encontrei as recomendações, mas nenhum exemplo claro de como implementá-las.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desculpe a resposta "jogada", mas nesse arquivo do Bootstrap vc pode apagar os `@imports` que vc não quer.

Depois que vc apagar os `@imports` que vc não quer vc precisa recompilar o `.SCSS` para gerar o seu novo `.CSS` apenas com o que vc precisa. Uma dica é vc renomear o seu arquivo `.SCSS`, pois se vc rodar alguma atualização ou reinstalar com `NPM` vc pode perder suas mudanças, pois o arquivo novo vai sobrescrever o seu.

Mas tenha atenção, alguns desses `@imports` são fundamentais para o bom funcionamento do Framework, por exemplo se vc deletar o import dos `transitions` a sua `navbar` pode ficar sem os efeitos de animação etc...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outros detalhes vc pode consultar nessa resposta como usar por exemplo apenas o Grid do Bootstrap etc [Gostaria de só usar o grid do bootstrap pra deixar responsivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/336229/gostaria-de-s%c3%b3-usar-o-grid-do-bootstrap-pra-deixar-responsivo/336232#336232)

---

**Sobre as classes "sujando" o HTML**

Recomendo que leia essa resposta [Como não repetir código CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/412137/como-n%c3%a3o-repetir-c%c3%b3digo-css/412151#412151)

Mas essa imagem  já responde a sua pergunta, quanto mais classe no HTML, menos código no CSS, e quanto menos classe no HTML, mais código no CSS...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E caso queira "extender" as propriedades de uma classe para outra vc pode usar o `@extent`

No exemplo abaixo ,usando SCSS vc pode colocar as propriedade da classe `.p-0` (padding: 0) nos elementos com a classe `.nav` e `.nav-item`

```
.nav,
.nav-item{
  @extend .p-0;
}
```

Mais detalhes vc pode ver nesse link que o autor da pergunta comentou https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-semantically-extend-bootstrap/

Comment: Entendi, comecei a comentar alguns desses imports ai para testar, e realmente ao recompilar o arquivo final ficou, até agora, com 400 linhas a menos, como não sei a utilidade de alguns desses arquivos, terei que fazer na tentativa e erro. É possível fazer o mesmo com os .js do bootstrap? pq no meu arquivo  ***home.ts*** eu estou importando tudo também `import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';`.

Comment: Para finalizar você poderia mostrar como eu faria para "enxugar" esse html para tirar essas classes html do bootstrap e fazer isso via sass, ou seja, repare que o código possui classes não semânticas como `class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"`, `class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0"`, etc. para os puristas isso é uma má prática. Como posso está tirando isso do html e colocando no meu ***home.scss***?

Comment: Apenas explicando melhor esse ultimo comentário. Queria encontrar uma forma de "extender"(alguma coisa parecida com @extend do sass) as classes do bootstrap para uma classe personalizada, assim ao invés de fazer `class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0"` eu poderia fazer algo como `class="btn-confirm"` e teria o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Encontrei esse [conteúdo](https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-semantically-extend-bootstrap/) que mostra como usar o sass para isso /\. Me parece que é exatamente como eu imaginei, é por meio do `@extend` do sass. Você pode acrescentar esse exemplo na sua resposta que eu marco como concluída. Também vou editar o título da pergunta.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva agora entendi melhor o que vc pretendia! Fiz o edite na resposta e inclusive inclui esse link que vc falou!

Comment: Afim de deixar um link seguro (que não venha a ficar off-line no futuro), sobre usar classes semânticas com bootstrap e sass, estou deixando uma [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716592/how-to-compose-multiple-classes-into-a-single-semantically-named-class) feita aqui na rede stack.

Comment: Hugão, já percebeu que o Chrome tá colocando um "outline" preto em tudo quanto é lugar? Links, elementos de formulário.

Comment: @Sam grande Tio, estou com Chrome no iOS e aqui est'a assim https://prnt.sc/snr7zb confere se nao eh alguma config de acessibilidade que vc ativou... o que eu tinha reparado 'e que Chrome mudou a cor dos inputs com autocomplete, mas j'a tem um tempo isso

Comment: @Sam olha ai https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/nic83#forms acho que foi esse o problema... mas parece que com um override simples pelo CSS vc muda esse outline (não testei ainda, mas acho que pode resolver)